# Mock window.crypto.getRandomValues in jest

Tags: javascript, mocking, cryptography, jestjs

I 'd like to mock `window.crypto.getRandomValues` in jest. I have tried `jest.spyOn` and it doesn't work out.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
   let byteArray = new Uint8Array(1)
   window.crypto.getRandomValues(byteArray)

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I'm working on react native and when running jest on unit test and the code inside js using 
   window.crypto.getRandomValues(byteArray) 
to create random values.
 Then, found the error message. 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRandomValues' of undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define the `window.crypto` property and its value.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  let byteArray = new Uint8Array(1);
  return window.crypto.getRandomValues(byteArray);
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';

describe('63484075', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mGetRandomValues = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(new Uint32Array(10));
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'crypto', {
      value: { getRandomValues: mGetRandomValues },
    });
    expect(main()).toEqual(new Uint32Array(10));
    expect(mGetRandomValues).toBeCalledWith(new Uint8Array(1));
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63484075/index.test.ts
  63484075
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.759s, estimated 13s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63484075